# Store and filter on list of values for a key in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

My database call returns a list of values for a key and I need to use Hazelcast as a cache in spring to store these values.

I am able to store it as (key, List) in IMap but by doing so I am unable to apply filters on these items for a key using something like Predicates for Hazelcast. I would also like it to support pagination for the list of values.

Already heard something about MultiMaps but unable to configure the same in springboot and also unsure whether it siffices the above use case.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Example: 
{userid1: [{accNum: , accType: }, { }],
userid2:  [{accNum: , accType: }, { }],....}

Now I want to filter on accType for userid1 by using predicates if possible.

Comment: Spring if you use `@Cacheable` and Hazelcast as the implementation will select an [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html). Spring chooses the implementation, it's not possible to select a different map type as the semantics will differ. A cache put of a singleton must mean a cache get returns a singleton not a collection. However, you can use predicates against keys or values, either can be a list -- so you can query into [collections(https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-in-collections-and-arrays) if you need.

Comment: So, continuing the comment... maybe there is a way, maybe not. Can you clarify the kind of search predicate you need to execute ?

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the response on this.Edited the question with an example. Please help clarify if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help any ?

It shows how you can query JSON objects

```
import java.util.Collection;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastJsonValue;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;
import com.hazelcast.query.Predicate;
import com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate;

public class Application {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> someMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("name goes here");

        String json1 = "{\"user\": 1, \"acc\": [{\"accNum\": 1, \"accType\": \"A\"}, {\"accNum\": 3, \"accType\": \"C\"}]";
        String json2 = "{\"user\": 2, \"acc\": [{\"accNum\": 2, \"accType\": \"B\"}, ]";

        HazelcastJsonValue value1 = new HazelcastJsonValue(json1);
        HazelcastJsonValue value2 = new HazelcastJsonValue(json2);

        someMap.put(1, value1);
        someMap.put(2, value2);

        String[] queries = {
                "user > 1",
                "acc[any].accType = 'C'",
                "acc[1].accType = 'C'",
                "acc[any].accType != 'C'",
                "acc[0].accType != 'C'",
        };

        for (String query : queries) {
            Predicate<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> predicate = new SqlPredicate(query);
            System.out.printf("%n%s%n", query);
            Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> results = someMap.values(predicate);
            results.forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.printf("[%d row%s]%n", results.size(), results.size()==1 ? "": "s");
        }

        hazelcastInstance.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks for the example code. Here I see you have used Jsonvalue but in my case its a list of jSonvalues per key as inthe example above

Comment: Hazelcast querying will need a `HazelcastJsonValue`