# How to use Hazelcast Predicate to filter entries in IMap with values as a List of objects

Tags: caching, hazelcast, predicate, hazelcast-imap

is there any way we can use predicates to filter entries in `IMap<String, List<Foo>>` where `MapStore`s value is a list of objects? I have a scenario like below:

```
  public class Foo {
      String bar;
      String foo
      String key;
      //Getters and Setters
  }
```

Using below method to fetch list of `Foo`s using `Predicate`.

```
      public List<Foo> getFooListByBar(String bar) {
        IMap<String, List<Foo>> fooListIMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap(FOO_MAP);
        Predicate predicate = Predicates.equal("bar",bar);
        Collection<List<Foo>> fooFiltered =  fooListIMap.values(predicate);
        //Other steps to retrieve list from Collection
     }
```

The above code is throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` as expected but I dont know how to achieve the above requirement. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'bar' on class 'java.util.ArrayList'
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.ReflectionHelper.createGetter(ReflectionHelper.java:171) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.instantiateGetter(Extractors.java:152) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.getGetter(Extractors.java:118) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.getters.Extractors.extract(Extractors.java:73) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValueFromTargetObject(QueryableEntry.java:171) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.extractAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:107) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry.getAttributeValue(QueryableEntry.java:61) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.readAttributeValue(AbstractPredicate.java:145) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
    at com.hazelcast.query.impl.predicates.AbstractPredicate.apply(AbstractPredicate.java:62) ~[hazelcast-3.12.6.jar:3.12.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query into collections.

See [Store and filter on list of values for a key in Hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181666/store-and-filter-on-list-of-values-for-a-key-in-hazelcast/61530513#61530513) for an example which is doing JSON but it's the same syntax for POJOs.

Or [Official Documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-in-collections-and-arrays).